# Cognos Reports Not Running As Scheduled

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

In Cognos Connection 10.2.2, we have scheduled reports that do not run as scheduled.  Most of these reports do not even show an attempt to run or any error in the run history log.

This report is scheduled to run daily.

Yet, it hasn't been updated in nearly a month.  The run log shows now errors or attempts to run at all.  I've tried modifying the [Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAdQ0.png) so that it would update but we continually get this problem.  Sometimes, there will be an attempt of the report running in the [Run History Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOaXa.png) but the status would say canceled, without an explanation.  No user would have manually canceled it so We're unsure of what that means.

The only way I can get this report to run is by manually running the report and saving it.

Is there something I might be doing wrong here.  This affects 100% of our reports.  Most reports will run once a month or twice a week but they're not consistent, even the though the schedule says daily.

Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your schedules don't even show any evidence that they are triggering and everything else in your Cognos environment looks like it's working well, I would check on the monitor service.  The [monitor service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.1.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.1.1.doc/c_enablingonlyservicesthatarerequired.html) is responsible for "the monitoring and execution of tasks that are scheduled, submitted for execution at a later time, or run as a background task."  The biggest clue you mention is that run history is not being generated for the scheduled reports, which tends to eliminate a whole class of problems (e.g. if the reports were attempting to run but failing).

In a distributed environment, this may run on all nodes or only certain nodes, so ensure that at least one node is running the service and then check the `cogserver.log` files during critical stages like Cognos startup and when a schedule is supposed to fire.  You may need to increase the logging level for that service to help figure out whether it is doing what it is supposed to be doing.

One problem that comes up with the monitor service, and if scheduled are intermittently succeeding I would check on this, is that not [all the nodes running the monitor service are configured to use the same notification store](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499572) or there is some problem accessing the tables, for example, database security.